# Why would I want use the plugins folder in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

The Nuxt `plugins` folder seems allows me to import modules, for instance `moment.js` into a `plugins/moment.js` file, and then import that `moment.js` file into my app for use. I'm struggling to understand I would want to do this when I could instead just import `moment.js` into my app directly?

What is the advantage of importing my modules into the plugins folder rather than just importing them directly into my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that it's more structured and easier to debug, we don't always use the plugins folder for that reason.

For instance, you can configure your plugin's options in plogin-name.js and importing that file into *nuxt-config.js*.

In this example, in *plugins/vuetify.js* you can add icons or colors to your theme.

```js
import UpIcon from "@/components/icons/UpIcon.vue";
import DownIcon from "@/components/icons/DownIcon.vue";
export default {
  icons: {
    values: {
      "arrow-up": { component: UpIcon },
      "arrow-down": { component: DownIcon },
    }
  }
};
```

or in this case, you don't even need to import it to your nuxt-config.js. it automatically detects it and applies it.